# C dynamic struct error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int size,choice;
    printf("student size:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    typedef struct 
    {
        int age;
        double gpa;
        char name[];
    }STUDENT;
    STUDENT *array = (STUDENT *) malloc(sizeof(STUDENT) * size);
    printf("\n(1) Add a student\n(2) Delete a student\n(3) Save all students\n(4)Quit\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    while (choice != 4){
        switch (choice) {
            STUDENT temp;
            STUDENT *tempptr = &temp;
            int cellNum;
            case 1:
                printf("Enter age gpa and name:\n");
                scanf("%d %f %s",&tempptr->age,&tempptr->gpa,&tempptr->name);
                printf("Enter cell number:\n");
                scanf("%d", &cellNum);
                if (cellNum > (size-1)){
                    printf("Invalid cell number\n");
                    break;
                }else{
                    *(array + cellNum) = temp;
                }
            case 3:
               printf("stupid c syntax rules");
               FILE *p = fopen("students.txt","w");
               int i = 0;
               for (i=0; i<size; i++){
                   fprintf(p, "%d, %f, %s\n",*(array+i).age,*(array+i).gpa,*(array+i).name);
               }
        }
        printf("\n(1) Add a student\n(2) Delete a student\n(3) Save all students\n(4)Quit\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

getting errors:

```
main.c:40:56: error: request for member 'age' in something not a structure or union                                      
                    fprintf(p, "%d, %f, %s\n",*(array+i).age,*(array+i).gpa,*(array+i).name);                            
                                                        ^                                                                
main.c:40:71: error: request for member 'gpa' in something not a structure or union                                      
                    fprintf(p, "%d, %f, %s\n",*(array+i).age,*(array+i).gpa,*(array+i).name);                            
                                                                       ^                                                 
main.c:40:86: error: request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union                                     
                    fprintf(p, "%d, %f, %s\n",*(array+i).age,*(array+i).gpa,*(array+i).name);
```

why is this happening? 
Thanks

Comment: `char name[];` needs size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` operator is a higher precedence than unary `*` (refer [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)). So first (before dereferencing) the compiler is trying to find an `age` field in `(array+i)`, which is not a structure, but a pointer.
 You want to replace the `*(array+i).age` by either `(array+i)->age` or `(*(array+i)).age`.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the error! Now im getting a segfault after executing the line                                                                                             scanf("%d %f %s",&tempptr->age,&tempptr->gpa,&tempptr->name);             do you know what the problem might be? Sorry, new to C

Comment: This is a different problem.

Comment: I know, thought I might ask though since it seems to be pretty small

Comment: Well, you don't have any space allocated for `name`.

Comment: I added in:STUDENT *tempptr = malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));
            tempptr = &temp;                                                                                    but still not working

Comment: The field `*name*` is a zero-sized array in your code. It needs space too. Either give it a size like `name[20]`, or allocate more space for the struct, as it is so called "flexible array member* (you can google it)